# How to pass ArrayList of ArrayLists between two activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Is there a way how to pass list of lists with my parcelable objects?

```
 public void listDataSms(ArrayList<MySmsLog> stringList) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(NUMBER_LIST, stringList);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyCommonListActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(WHO_INT, SMS_LOG);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(i, SMS_LOG);
```

i have this working but now i need to pass this somehow

```
public void listDataSmsAll(ArrayList<ArrayList<MySmsLog>> stringList)
```

Comment: You can serialize it into a JSON string and pass it with the bundle and deserialize it in the receiving Activity.
You can also save it in the Application object.

Comment: If its array you use often then put it inside database and retrieve anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be letting your custom class implement `Serializable` interface and then you can pass object instances in intent extra using `putExtra(Serializable..)` variant of the `Intent#putExtra()` method.

PSEUDO code:

```
//to pass :
   intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

[How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: I know that way but i´m not using static fields anymore. Wanna keep it in object principle.

Comment: This approach results in an unchecked cast warning when retrieving the object.